# reintegrate workflow

Tags: svn

Hallo experts,

A simple question from me, an old newbie to Tortoise SVN.

I'm working on a branch, and want now to merge the changes in my branch (after commit) to the trunk. However I'm not sure about the correct workflow. Should I first merge the trunk to my working copy, after resolving all the possible conflicts, then reintegrate my branch to the trunk? Since most of my colleague are still in holidays, I cannot get any advices on such basics in my team.

Thanks a lot in advance,

John in Munich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Not sure what else to add given that you said it all :)

It's worth noting that the reintegrate feature basically makes your branch useless for further development so it must be the last step ever, right before branch deletion, so try to avoid until you're fully sure that the code is production ready. If unsure, you can do a regular merge from branch to trunk. Why the feature even exists is something that I've never been able to grasp; I suppose it's a side effect of Subversion's poor merge tracking.

I also suggest you don't perform all merges at once and, instead, try to divide them into smaller sets and commit your work between merges. If you get a merge conflict you can't easily fix you want to be able to revert.

**Update:** The official **Version Control with Subversion** books says this:

> In Subversion 1.5, once a
>   --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no
>   longer usable for further work. It's
>   not able to correctly absorb new trunk
>   changes, nor can it be properly
>   reintegrated to trunk again. For this
>   reason, if you want to keep working on
>   your feature branch, we recommend
>   destroying it and then re-creating it
>   from the trunk

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate

Comment: Thanks for your advices. As i said, i'm a newbie to Tortoise SVN. i just ask for confirmation of your suggestion: Do mean that merge branch to trunk (instead of final reintegrate) should be done in the working copy of the trunk?

Comment: @JohnMunich I always do so. There're many situations where changes to trunk need to be adapted to changes to branch (e.g., you change a function signature in branch and you add new invocations in trunk). I find it easier to have a fully functional branch to test before the final port.

Comment: In the dialog Windows of regular merge and reintegrate i cannot find any big difference (I mean from * to * can be identically specified.). Reintegrate cannot be carried out more than twice? What could be an issue during the second reintegrate?

Comment: @JohnMunich, docs say *once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no longer usable for further work*. I'm updating the answer with a proper quote.

Answer (score 0):

First commit the changes that you made in your branch in to svn.

Then use merge feature (with specific revision number) of svn to merge from your branch to other branch (or main/trunk). Once you have the merged changes (all conflicts resolved) in your local copy of 'the other branch (main/trunk)', commit those changes back to svn and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We're using Tortoise SVN. According to your description, i formulate the following workflow: 1. Commit the changes to my branch 2. Reintegrate (merge branch to trunk with necessary resolving conflicts) 3. Commit. It seems that after reintegrate (merge from branch to trunk) the changes will be applied to the trunk and my working copy, but except the branch. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ John, yes, If you have to merge the changes from 'trunk' in to your branch as well, you can follow the same procedure again for your branch.

Comment: Still questions: 1. Should the reintegrate be done in the working copy of the trunk? 2. Should the second commit also be done in the working copy of the trunk? Sorry for the further questions.

Comment: Yes, reintegrate should be done in the working copy of trunk and after that, the changes (occurred after merging) in trunk will have to be committed in the svn. Don't worry too much about it, you can always revert your changes in svn if any thing goes wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the way to go.

As you probably have a feature branch, what you have to do is described in the [SVN redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature).

To paraphrase:

1. Merge `trunk` into your branch
2. Merge your branch into `trunk` using the `reintegrate` parameter

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is the "Merge trunk into your branch" necessary? It seems not be concluded in the answer from Vikram.exe.

Comment: As far as I know: yes, it is important. Subversion keeps track of the merge history of a branch in the `mergeinfo` property. It will automatically be handled by the `merge` command but only contain all necessary information if the trunk has been merged into the branch before.